# How to get the data directly to test case from an excel file

Tags: python, excel, selenium, robotframework

I am using robot framework and I am getting error while trying to get the data directly from excel to the Test case.

Code given below :

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Resource   ../Resources/reusableComponents.robot
Library    DataDriver    ../TestData/Config.xlsx  sheet_name=Config

*** Variables ***
${txt_Username}      //*[@id="UserName"]
${txt_Password}     //*[@id="Password"]
${btn_Login}        //*[@id="btnLogin"]
${txt_HomePage}     Station ID

    enter code here
    

***** Test Cases ***  
Login scenarios
        Input Text    ${txt_Username}  ${username}
        Input Text    ${txt_Password}    ${password}
        Click Button    ${btn_Login}
```

Error says "Variable 'username' is used, but not defined", How should I define? also, I dont want to use Test Template as I am not running the same test case multiple times

Comment: The error is for this line `Input Text    ${txt_Username}  ${username}` . Have you defined `'keyword` for your `${username}`?  Or does your Excel file has the same header name as `username`? Check these and it should be resolved I think.

Comment: Excel file has the same header name as ${username}

Answer (score 0):

DataDriver library uses test templates and they are a bit confusing. In my example, I have an Excel file with two columns: "${username}" and "${password}".

```
*** Settings ***
Library    DataDriver    file=myExcel.xlsx   sheet_name=Sheet1
Test Template            LogUsenameAndPassword

*** Keywords ***
LogUsenameAndPassword
    [Arguments]       ${username}    ${password}
    Log To Console    ${username}
    Log To Console    ${password}

***Test Cases ***
Log Usename ${username} And Password ${password}
```

Comment: Do we have any alternative method without using Test Template. I just need to run an end to end test case and data will be from excel.

Comment: If you only need the contents of cells, you could use ExcelLibrary to read them.